# Limit custom object to user territory

Tags: custom-object, territory

I have a custom object and custom tab for it.
It has Lookup relationship to Account.

Currently user can view all custom object records.

But I want to limit access to custom object using user's territory permission.

How can I do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you know... found answer just after posting.

I've changed the Lookup Relationship to Master-Detail Relationship, and magic happened!

Comment: Master-detail inherits the sharing of the parent, so they only get access if they can see the parent.